# Nix: Propagate dependency for build-time but NOT for run-time?

Tags: docker, nix, header-only

I am packaging the following derivations.

- A C++ library named `amazing` that has a header-only C++ dependency ([nlohmann_json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) for this example).
  The library must be dynamic (shared ELF file).
  The `amazing` library requires the `nlohmann_json` dependency at build-time but not as run-time (as `nlohmann_json` is header-only).
  The users of `amazing` also require `nlohmann_json` at build-time, otherwise they will have a compilation error.
  But users do not need `nlohmann_json` at run-time.
- A C++ executable named `example` that uses the `amazing` library.
- A docker container named `example-docker` that just wraps a compiled version of `example`.
  I want the container to contain **all** needed run-time dependencies of `example` but to remain minimal — i.e., it should **not** contain `nlohmann_json`.

I have created a [self-contained minimal git repository](https://github.com/mpoquet/nix-propagation-build-time-only) for this example.

My current Nix setup looks like this.

```hs
{ pkgs ? import (fetchTarball {
    url = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/21.11.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "162dywda2dvfj1248afxc45kcrg83appjd0nmdb541hl7rnncf02";
  }) {}
}:

let
  self = rec {
    nlohmann_json = pkgs.nlohmann_json;
    amazing = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
      pname = "amazing";
      version = "local";
      src = pkgs.lib.sourceByRegex ./lib [
        "amazing\..pp"
        "meson\.build"
      ];
      nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [ meson ninja pkgconfig ];
      propagatedBuildInputs = [ nlohmann_json ];
    };
    example = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
      pname = "example";
      version = "local";
      src = pkgs.lib.sourceByRegex ./example [
        "example\.cpp"
        "meson\.build"
      ];
      nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [ meson ninja pkgconfig amazing ];
    };
    example-docker = pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage {
      name = "example";
      tag = "latest";
      contents = [ example ];
      config = {
        Entrypoint = [ "${example}/bin/example" ];
      };
    };
  };
in
  self
```

The Nix setup works (all derivations build correctly and the container runs fine),
but the container is not minimal: `nlohmann_json` is in the container.

I tried several ways to define the `nlohmann_json` input of `amazing` so that
derivations that use `amazing` have `nlohmann_json` at build-time but without forcing the presence of `nlohmann_json` in the final container (`propagatedNativeBuildInputs`, `depsBuildBuildPropagated` from the [nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/)),
but I could not achieve the desired result.
I also tried to use `strictDeps = true;` but I could not build my derivations in this case.

Is it possible to achieve what I want with Nix?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer, but you might look at `disallowedReferences` (see [here](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/expressions/advanced-attributes.html)). This and `nixpkgs.removeReferenceTo` are meant for this situation. Here are a [couple](https://jade.fyi/blog/optimizing-nix-docker/) of [examples](https://githee.netsoj.nl/chris/kerstezel-ober/commit/e3a323b8d967ef30f1617f16533e586db3240015?style=unified&whitespace=ignore-eol) I found of it in use.

But I messed around with your example for a while with various combinations of `disallowedReferences`/`allowedReferences` and remove-reference-to in your example derivation, along with various places to put `nlohmann_json` in the dependencies for `amazing`. I couldn't get it to work. `nlohmann_json`  was always included, or Meson would complain that it couldn't find `amazing`. So something about removing the references to `nlohmann_json` ended up throwing out all of `amazing`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to use propagatedNativeBuildInputs. See https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/stdenv/stdenv.chapter.md#propagatednativebuildinputs-var-stdenv-propagatednativebuildinputs for the doc.